# If there is any function in firefox to get all indexedDB names?

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb, pouchdb, firefox-developer-tools

In chrome, I used `window.indexedDB.databases()` method to get all indexedDb names.

But that same method is not wokring in firefox.

I will also try `window.indexedDB.databases()` similar methods like `window.indexedDB.webkitdatabases()` & `window.indexedDB.mozwebkitdatabases()`.

For the above methods implementation will get the following error.

> window.indexedDB.databases() is not a function.

Also I will try to use the indexedDB interfaces like IDBObjectStore,IDBDataBase...etc. But there is no use. They also give error in its implementation.

So kindly give some proper method or suggestion to get all indexedDB names.

Comment: you can read about firefox API in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: Thanks for your response.I already refered bro.But No solution there.So if you know the proper solution kindly guide me.

Comment: Sorry for shameless self-promo (which also happens to be a year late), but I've made a simple polyfill that adds `databases` method to `indexedDB` on Firefox: [GitHub Gist link](https://gist.github.com/yohgen/bdb22fc8a535ad4d934362a82c3e62e4). For some reason I failed to find any polyfills that target that specific issue

Answer (score 2):

you have a method inside IDBFactory that give you the database list.

> IDBFactory.databases
> A method that returns a list of all available databases, including their names and versions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory
but it is was not actually implemented !!
you can read more on that in [firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934640)

So the only way to get the database names is by using the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) within the Firefox DevTools.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But that method is not available in firefox.Kindly check your shared link browser compatablity table & one more thing I am already mentioned the method in my question.

So kindly provide some proper solution.

Comment: you are right. i edit my answer. it is probably will not happen soon. they have an archtecture problem that the need to solve first if the want to fix this bug. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934640

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to get the database names at the moment (as of Firefox 92) is by using the Storage Inspector. You will have to wait until the API is implemented to have access to them via JavaScript. I have added that info to the answer.

Comment: Well, this is actually sad and ridiculous. By now Jan 2022, it's still not supported and for my project it is a crucial feature. Would probably have to use localstorage to add/remove items when adding/removing to indexeddb

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel already 2 years, now is 2023 and mozilla has not yet added that feature, you guys have some work-arounds?

Comment: @Dee in the link of bugzila in the end of disccion there are some solutions  bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934640